# Hide a JTable row with click event [ java ]

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jbutton, actionlistener

I have JTable like this

[image]

I want to hide the row whenever the respective clear button(JButton) is pressed.And do other task such delete the row from mysql as the table is populated form database.

As i have two override function :-

one:

```
   public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
        boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column)
```

two:

```
  public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value,
  boolean isSelected, int row, int column)
```

where and how i have to change to achieve this.Or any other implementations details that would help me.Thanks

Comment: `I want to clear hide the row whenever the respective clear button(JButton) is pressed.` my question (coud be important, maybe not depends of) is to hide only or to delete (forever after JDBC is executed with success)

Comment: hide form this table and delete forever form database.My problem is how catch the action of the clear button .thanks @mKorbel

Comment: search here for [java] [swing] [jtable] [jbutton], there are a few interesting Q&As about similair issue

Comment: Are you asking how to attach a listener to a JButton?  Or..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Table Button Column](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/) shows one way to add an ActionListener to a column of a table.

Comment: public ButtonColumn(JTable table, Action action, int column) What is the action parameter to be passed ?? Thanks. – sharif

Comment: @sharif, The Action of the Clear button.

Answer (score 1):

So basically you want the `JButton` to delete the row from your `TableModel`.  You haven't shown any of the relevant code, or what kind of `TableModel` you have, but generally:

-write the listener, it will need a way to access your model

```
class MyListener
    implements ActionListener
{
    private TableModel model;

    public MyListener( TableModel m )
    {
        this.model = m;
    }

    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e )
    {
        // do something to this.model
    }
}
```

-attach it to your button

```
button.addActionListener( new MyListener(myModel) );
```

-lastly, realize that what you're looking at in the table is not a fully-featured JButton, but instead just a cell that's painted to *look* like a button.  It still won't work when you click on it, even though you attached a listener.

You need to work around this last issue.  There are a number of different approaches, many of which are laid out in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10347983/making-a-jbutton-clickable-inside-a-jtable) thread.  The most basic is to hijack the cell editor to have it forward mouse events to the JButton, that's what I've done in the past.  There are some other options in the linked thread.  Good luck.