# Dynamic Jframe and Jtable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am coding a small script and stuck on this issue. This is my scripts screenshot.

[image]

In `... button` it should be automaticly open the browse and the user can select the directory.
In addition If the user click the `+ Button` , the script should create a new path place and the user can select the second path. The problem is how can I add the second or third path place to the gui without damage general view. Like `Show Me` button has to always seems in gui.

For this problem what is your advice ? Should I use first JScrollPane and then Jtree? or more easy way?

I need your helps and some tricks.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd suggest using a [JList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) in a [JScrollPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) for displaying the added paths.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355544/how-to-implement-dynamic-gui-in-swing). I'd just use a single selection double column JTable (path string, browse button), though. Also check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10347983/making-a-jbutton-clickable-inside-a-jtable).