# Css with pure swing?

Tags: java, css, swing, netbeans

In pure swing based application i want to create a button in J table using CSS and give action when click the button.I have no idea with swing but last time i do with JSP now i want to handling with CSS button in J table because i cant understand the rendering with drag and drop there is no complete step by step procedure that how to add update and delete button automatically against every id when record show in J table while in JSP with CSS i do it last time guide me with comprehensive example thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making a JButton clickable inside a JTable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10347983/making-a-jbutton-clickable-inside-a-jtable)

Comment: First, take a look at [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html).  Next, change the way you are thinking.  Buttons in tables are so, frankly, 80's web design.  Instead, you should have a single button, maybe on a toolbar, which can be used to delete the selected rows from the table, believe me, your users will thank you when they need to delete 200 rows...

Comment: This character `.` is very useful when writing questions.

Comment: Sir i want a table which every row have a update and delete button i also read your ans in another question like"Column Button rendering " but i want a easy way using drag and drop and i have no idea that when i create a J table using drag and drop then how to change his code while in netbean it is no allowed please give me idea to add button using drag and drop in Jtable thanks a lot.

Comment: Tanks to Every one i will try my best to solve thanks for guidance.